# Marshalling char *

Tags: c#, .net, c++, visual-c++

i have the following method signature on my c++ dll:

```
extern char *bpStringCalc(char *bpDirectory, char *issString);
```

And i'm trying to call it from c# using this:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\MuniAxis\Bp\BpDLL.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
public static extern string bpStringCalc([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string bpDirectory,
                                         [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string issString);
```

But it keep getting this exception:

> 'ConsoleApplication1!ConsoleApplication1.Program::bpStringCalc'
>   has unbalanced the stack. This is
>   likely because the managed PInvoke
>   signature does not match the unmanaged
>   target signature. Check that the
>   calling convention and parameters of
>   the PInvoke signature match the target
>   unmanaged signature.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I remember you're going to have more luck using `StringBuilder` instead of string.

Comment: Be sure to pin the string instance in memory before calling the method.

Comment: @BrokenGlass: It should make no difference given the arguments aren't the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying a `Cdecl` calling convention on import or `__stdcall` on export. See [this almost similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070752/simple-interop-test-stack-unbalanced-by-a-simple-call).

Comment: +1 for similar question link and for (correctly) putting two underscores before `__stdcall`, which I screwed up initially :)

Comment: This is the answer. C++ defaults to `__cdecl` but for some insane reason, P/Invoke defaults to `__stdcall`.

Comment: @DeadMG `DllImport` defaults to `Winapi`, which selects either `StdCall` or `Cdecl` depending on the platform.

Comment: @DeadMG: It defaults to `__stdcall` because the most common use of P/Invoke is to call Win32 functions, and all of Win32 uses `__stdcall`.

Comment: @Billy: It was hard to not provide the link, considering I answered that question few minutes earlier :)

Answer (score 4):

Unbalancing the stack probably has more to do with calling convention than it does the actual arguments. C++, by default, uses the `__cdecl` calling convention. C# defaults to `__stdcall` because `__stdcall` is the convention used by Win32. You need to either set [calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx) on your import statement in C#, or you need to specify `__stdcall` in your C++ binary.

**EDIT**: The above was edited to fix the fact that `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` had only one leading underscore each ;)